# Delete opvn config after a specific amount of time

Tags: openvpn

On an Ubuntu VPS, how do I delete a specific config (aka client) after a determined amount of time?
Let's suppose I create `client1.opvn`
How can I delete it **after 100 hours automatically** ?
I only know how to instantly delete it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to make a shell script to count down:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Set x to 100
x=100
#Convert it to hours
x=$(expr $x "*" 60)
#infinite
while true
do
#If x is greater than 0
    if [ $x -gt 0 ]
    then
        x=$(expr $x - 1)
        echo "$x minutes left."
        sleep 60
    else
        #Put code to delete here
        echo "Deleting..."
        /path/to/revoke-full name client
        exit
    fi
done
```

Although this should work, I haven't had the time to test it.

I got `expr` help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218141/multiplication-with-expr-in-shell-script

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have always used this command. Is there a way it can be adapted to your script ?

./revoke-full name_of_the_client

Comment: I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not schedule removal with `cron` ?

```
crontab -e 
0 */100 * * * /bin/rm path_to_ovpn
```

Comment: That would run every 100 hours, not just once.

Comment: Yes, it was OP point I believe. I don't know how to read minds.